# how to launch jQuery Overlay from PHP and using `rel` attr?

Tags: php, jquery, overlay, launch

I need to launch jQuery Overlay in two (call them three) situations:

1. From HTML button (using `rel` attr.)
2. When called from PHP
3. (2a) (to remain opened) after $_POST submit.

For (1) and (2) I tried this:

```
//my js func
function triggerOverlay(elem){

    if(!elem){
        elem = "button[rel]";
        load = false;
    }else{
        load = true;
    }

    $(elem).overlay({
        top         : 'center',
        closeOnClick: false   ,
        load        : load   ,
        speed       : 0,
    });
};

//call from html file
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php
//I'm calling Launch::init(); from where I need to launch it, and it sets self::$open_overlay = TRUE;
    if(Launch::$open_overlay){
        echo 'var elem = "#orderOverlay";'."\r\n";
    }
    ?>
        if(!elem){
           var elem = false;
        }
        triggerOverlay(elem);
    });
</script>
```

The problem with this one is that var **elem** will prevent using button after I call PHP `Launch::init()`. So, I need another approach, which will let me use both manual and automated launch of jQuery Overlay.

*Then, I will take care of step (3)-> I will send same command as on (2) when I reload the page, after submitting form.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `jQuery tools` plugin for overlay there are examples and docs for managing an overlay  programmatically. Look at `Scripting API` on docs page and demo for `Opening overlays programmatically`

You can open an overlay within a form submit handler, or element click handler using :

```
   $(selector).overlay().load();
```

Reference : http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html

If you are not using `jQuery tools` look at API for plugin you are using

Comment: I did that. As you may see in my example, the programmatic call is as exemplified in jQuery Tools example. My problem is NOT **how** to call the script, but **how to implement that, in order to be valid simultaneous as button call and called from PHP**. Please read carefully: after I call from PHP, that freqkin' variable `elem` is still there and prevents me to call from button. Ok, I could unset it, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. Maybe is a better way to do it "clean".

Comment: I did read carefully... your logic is not right. You just need to set up an overlay element and add a click handler for your button that will call  `$('#myOverlayDiv').overlay().load();` and call the same after you submit

Comment: I attached it on `onclick` event to button, as you told me, but the overlay triggered only on second click. To fix that, I had to do it this way: `$('#myOverlayDiv').overlay({load:true}).load();`

Comment: I haven't used that API for long time... ay least got you steered in right direction, glad it worked out. Can also define `'load` in options I believe